# CMake is not creating a Makefile (Trying to Install GODDeSS-Package)

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, cmake, zlib

I am very new (my first time) to installing software through command lines and source files and C++. So the solution could be quite simple but I just simply don't understand it.

My objective here is to install the GODDeSS-Package following these [instructions](https://git.rwth-aachen.de/3pia/forge/goddess-package/-/wikis/Installation_and_Usage).
I am currently under the section "How to install the example simulation" and I am stuck on the final step (step 8). To my knowledge, I believe I have installed all the prerequisite software correctly listed from steps 1-3.

Following the procedures when I arrive at step 8, I execute the following command and receive this error:

```
$cmake C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/Research/GODDeSS-Package/goddess-package/GODDeSS_4_3/source

...
Could NOT find Boost (missing: regex) (found version "1.59.0")
...
```

I used the ellipse to show there is text before and after that error message. However this is not the main problem. I was able to over come this with a add-on argument (which I don't really understand how it works) **-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON**

So after this modification, I get the following results:

```
$cmake C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/Research/GODDeSS-Package/goddess-package/GODDeSS_4_3/source -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON

...
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/Research/GODDeSS-Package/goddess-build
```

So I assume part 1 of step 8 done correctly? ...since it says "Generating done".

Now here is where I run into the problem. the next command is:

```
$make -j install
```

But I don't have a Makefile in the generated files!

Here is a picture of my build directory which I have generated the files into:

[Build Directory Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZc2e.png)

I have done some reading and it seems like cmake is Building for Visual Studios 16 2019 so it creates the .sln files instead (theres alot of them! Almost one in every folder). I'm not entire sure how to deal with this situation. Instead I tried to force cmake to generate me a Makefile by using the add-on command **-G "MinGW Makefiles"** I picked MinGW randomly just because it was one of the few options that generated a Makefile.

So I created a fresh build directory and used the following command:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/James_L_Pinfold_Research/GODDeSS-Package/goddess-package/GODDeSS_4_3/source -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON
```

But I get the following error:

`CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

So now I'm stuck... I see 2 paths I can go down. 1. Make use of the .sln files created by cmake to install the package... or 2. Somehow make cmake create a Makefile so I can use the make command. Neither of which how to do.

I'm having a hard time trying to find documentations of how to install this package but I have yet to succeed. What can I try next?

I am using Windows 10, Terminal: Git Bash, Visual Studios 2019, Boost_1_5_9, zlib1211, geant4_10_02_p03, and cmake-3.17.2

Comment: Have you tried building the target with the VS solution files? It should work, it's definitely more likely to work than picking a random development environment which you don't have installed.

Comment: All of the instructions for this repository appear to be catered for a Linux operating system, but you are using Windows. So yes, the `make` executable will not be available by default on Windows. So instead, you can continue down the Visual Studio approach to build/install (open the Simulation.sln file). You might run into other issues though, since it isn't clear from a quick browse of the repository whether or not this software is supported on Windows.

Comment: Hi guys! Thank for helping. There is many .sln files in each of the folders, so am I suppose to open each one up and build them individually?

Comment: Normally simulation.sln would build everything

Comment: It would build everything even if there is other .sln in the subdirectories?